Quickly Retrieve Elevations Inside a Room
Is there something similar to an ElementIntersectsSolidFilter that I would use to find all the ElevationMarkers, or Views, that exist within a specific Room?
Our View naming standard for Elevations should include the Room Name and Room Number and I'm trying to automate the renaming of those Elevations when a user changes the Room Name.
I've written a DMU that works by creating a temporary Floor Plan View (tempView) and
using a FilteredElementCollector:
List<ElevationMarker> markersMaybeInRoom = new FilteredElementCollector(doc, tempView.Id)
    .OfClass(typeof(ElevationMarker))
    .WhereElementIsNotElementType()
    .Cast<ElevationMarker>()
    .Where(e => e.HasElevations())
    .ToList();

foreach (ElevationMarker marker in markersMaybeInRoom)
{
    BoundingBoxXYZ emBB = marker.get_BoundingBox(tempView);
    double x = emBB.Max.X - offset;
    double y = emBB.Max.Y - offset;

    XYZ markerLocation = new XYZ(x, y, tempView.GenLevel.ProjectElevation);

    Room markerRoom = doc.GetRoomAtPoint(markerLocation, roomPhase);
    if (markerRoom == null)
        continue; // ElevationMarker is not in a Room

    if (markerRoom.Id != room.Id)
        continue; // ElevationMarker is not in the modified Room

    markersInRoom.Add(marker);
}

This is just ridiculously slow, though, because of the number of Elements in our models.  I know a quicker way would be to use ExtensibleStorage to store the Unique ID of the Room when creating the Elevations and setup a DMU for those associated IDs.  I'm trying to avoid that, though, because it will only work on models moving forward versus a FilteredElementCollector that could work on any model.

I would suggest a completely different approach, hopefully much more efficient:

iterate over all the levels and/or elevations and determine a sorted list A of all their  Z coordinates in the local project coordinate system.
iterate over all the rooms and determine the Z coordinates of their upper and lower extents.
implement a comparison and sorting algorithm to check which room [bottomZ,topZ] intervals overlap which which entries in A.


If I'm reading this correctly, I'd still have to iterate over each of the entries in A to determine if they are in the changed Room. My problem would be, I don't have a specific point inside each of those entries that could be tested against doc.GetRoomAtPoint.

I thought that each level has an elevation, that I would consider its bottom, and most have another neighbour elevation above, which I would consider its top. Each [bottom,top] pair defines an interval. Then, for a given point P, you can check which of the intervals contains P.Z.

I think we're talking about different "Elevations."  I was looking for ViewType.Elevation Elevations and I think you're talking about Elevations, as in a Z coordinate in the model.  :)

I was able to do something similar to Jeremy's approach, although it's unique to my situation. When we create an Interior Elevation (which is what I'm trying to find) I have a DMU that adds a FilledRegion around the perimeter of the View to give us a thick line and hide modeled Elements we don't want to see. The benefit of having these is they're consistent and Model Sketch Lines.  Using that, I used a BoundingBoxIsInsideFilter of the Room's BoundingBox:
GeometryElement roomGeometry = room.ClosedShell;
BoundingBoxXYZ roomBB = roomGeometry.GetBoundingBox();

BoundingBoxIsInsideFilter bbFilter = new BoundingBoxIsInsideFilter(new Outline(roomBB.Min, roomBB.Max));
ElementCategoryFilter catFilter = new ElementCategoryFilter(BuiltInCategory.OST_SketchLines);

IEnumerable<Element> sketchLinesMaybeInRoom = new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
    .WherePasses(bbFilter)
    .WherePasses(catFilter)
    .Where(e => e.GetType().Name == "DetailLine");

IEnumerable<View> viewsMaybeInRoom = sketchLinesMaybeInRoom
    .Select(e => e.OwnerViewId)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(e => doc.GetElement(e))
    .Where(e => e.Name.StartsWith("IE - ")
        || e.Name.StartsWith("IEE - ")
        || e.Name.StartsWith("UIE - "))
    .Cast<View>();

foreach (View view in viewsMaybeInRoom)
{
    Phase viewPhase = doc.GetElement(view.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.VIEW_PHASE)
        .AsElementId()) as Phase;

    Element sketchLine = sketchLinesMaybeInRoom
        .Where(e => e.OwnerViewId == view.Id)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    DetailLine lineCurve = sketchLine as DetailLine;
    XYZ point = lineCurve.GeometryCurve.GetEndPoint(0);

    Room viewRoom = doc.GetRoomAtPoint(point, viewPhase);

    if (viewRoom.Id != room.Id)
        continue;
    
    // Code to update the View as required
}

It makes a couple assumptions, which will cause it to fail sometimes, but it's a start.
